# Strange Margin showing up in a flexbox

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

I have tried negative margins and other hacks but as far as i know, there shouldn't be any margins there in the first place. With just a simple box i can get zero margins between the tags but somehow the stuff outside that is messing with it.

The problem is with the neon blue badges in the bottom right corner.

```css
.info{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    // justify-content: space-between;
}
.column {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 48%;
    min-height: 61.9px;
    // background-color: #00ffff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.info-block{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
}
.spacer{
    height:14.7px;
    width: 1px;
}
.tag{
 line-height: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 15.8px;
    width:40px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    background-color: #00ffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.tag-container{
    line-height: 0;
    width: 168px;
    height:78px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    
}
.tag-text{
 width:20px;
 font-family: HelveticaNeue-Bold;
 font-size: 8px;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-stretch: normal;
 text-align: center;
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="info-block">
                <div class="info-header">Location</div>
                <div class="info-text">place</div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
             <div class="info-block">
                <div class="info-header">Mobile</div>
                <div class="info-text">+44 (0) 788-588</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column"> 
             <div class="info-block">
                <div class="info-header">Menu</div>
                <div class="info-text"><a>bk.com</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <div class="info-block ">
                <div class="info-header">Tags</div>
                <div class="tag-containter">

                    <div class="tag"><div class="tag-text">h</div></div>
                    <div class="tag"><div class="tag-text">Som</div></div>
                    <div class="tag"><div class="tag-text">Somethg</div></div>
                    <div class="tag">
                        <div class="tag-text">ng</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tag">
                        <div class="tag-text">Somhing</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `//` is not a correct way to comment CSS

Comment: @oriol, it is not a duplicate, a class is mispeled and flex not triggered , i reopen the question

Comment: @GCyrillus Then it's off-topic - simple typographical error

Comment: @Oriol oh yes, agreed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only made a silly mistake.
Just check your class name .tag-containter in css and html.

you use .tag-container instead of tag-containter class.

Answer (score 1):

you mispelled the class tag-container either in the html (tag-contain**t**er) or in the css . notice the extra T in html and missing in css selector

```css
.info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* justify-content: space-between;*/
}
.column {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 48%;
  min-height: 61.9px;
  /* background-color: #00ffff;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.info-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.spacer {
  height: 14.7px;
  width: 1px;
}
.tag {
  line-height: 0;
  height: 15.8px;
  width: 40px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  background-color: #00ffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.tag-containter {
  width: 168px;
  height: 78px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.tag-text {
  font-family: HelveticaNeue-Bold;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="info-block">
      <div class="info-header">Location</div>
      <div class="info-text">place</div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="info-block">
      <div class="info-header">Mobile</div>
      <div class="info-text">+44 (0) 788-588</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="info-block">
      <div class="info-header">Menu</div>
      <div class="info-text"><a>bk.com</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="info-block ">
      <div class="info-header">Tags</div>
      <div class="tag-containter">

        <div class="tag">
          <div class="tag-text">h</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tag">
          <div class="tag-text">Som</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tag">
          <div class="tag-text">Somethg</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tag">
          <div class="tag-text">ng</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tag">
          <div class="tag-text">Somhing</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.tag` is set to `display: inline-block;`, which is an inline element. Spaces between inline elements are preserved in HTML, so if you have spaces (or returns) between the elements, you will see a space between the elements on the page. To remove the spaces between the `.tag` boxes, remove the actual spaces between those elements.